# showing NaN instead of 0 miles

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to calculate the distance in miles using Geodist. The miles are calculated accurately. the only issues is when the longitude and latitude of the current location is same as longitude and latitude of the destination location then I get "NaN" instead of 0 miles. I am not sure how to fix this NaN value. I tried to do this:

```
  if (item.cLat === item.LatL)
            dist: 0
```

still I am getting NaN when the longitude and latitude is same for current location and destination. Below is my code and Json file:

```
var geodist = require('geodist')
 var dist = geodist({lat: item.cLat, lon:item.cLong}, {lat: item.LatL, lon: item.Long2}, 'mi')
    if (item.cLat === item.LatL)
            dist: 0

return(
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: index %2 ===0? '#ffdfba':'#bae1ff'}} >

  <Text style={styles.AddressSpace} >Miles:{dist}</Text>



               </View>
)
```

My Json file is like this:

[

```
{
   "id":"1",
   "fk": 1,
   "addr": "101 test drive",
   "phone": "(951)-955-6200",
   "LatL":"33.123456",
   "Long2":"117.923456",
   "cLat": "33.123456",
   "cLong": "117.923456",

}
```

]

Comment: make dist:0 to dist = 0

Comment: I already tried dist=0. still showing "NaN'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already noted in the comments, you don't set the value of dist with `dist : 0`.  You set it with `dist = 0`.  `dist : 0` is only appropriate when you are setting `dist` as a property in an object, like: `var someObject = { dist : 0 };`.  And for the love of all that is holy, man - get some semicolons.  They don't hurt.

But I put this as a full-fledged "answer" (rather than just another comment) because the condition in your sample code *is only checking for equivalent latitudes*.  So in your example, even after you fix the `dist : 0` problem, it will show a distance of zero for any two locations that share the same latitude, *even if they have a different longitudes*.  So you need to have something like this:

```
if (item.cLat === item.LatL && item.cLong === item.Long2) {
    dist = 0;
}
```

But if you're *still* seeing `NaN`, then the most complete solution would be to simply check for that specific condition.  So you could discard the whole `if (item.cLat === item.LatL && item.cLong === item.Long2)` and replace it with this:

```
if (isNan(dist)) {
    dist = 0;
}
```

And just for reference, here's a link to the isNaN() function:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Comment: I had to use isNaN(dist) and it worked right away. Thank you very much!! The other solution was not working.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because lat and lon are strings not numeric. Try forcing them to be numeric like this:

```js
var geodist = require('geodist')
 var dist = geodist({lat: +item.cLat, +lon:item.cLong}, {lat: +item.LatL, lon: +item.Long2}, 'mi')
    if (item.cLat === item.LatL)
            dist: 0

return(
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: index %2 ===0? '#ffdfba':'#bae1ff'}} >

  <Text style={styles.AddressSpace} >Miles:{dist}</Text>



               </View>
)
```

Comment: In the example he's given above, `item.cLat` and `item.LatL` are indeed strings.  But there is no reason that you'd have to convert them to numbers to compare them.  Using his sample data, `item.cLat === item.LatL` evaluates to `TRUE`.